# Kill a Storm topology that contains special char in topology name

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

So, it just so happened that I got a Storm topology from one of their examples (storm-starter), deployed by the name `-local`. Now it isn't too happy when I'm trying to `kill` it because the name is being interpreted as an argument. I have tried passing the name in (double) quotes, etc. in vain. Is there any other way?

Comment: Ok guys, since I could not find an 'elegant' way to deal with the issue, I went ahead by getting rid of the zookeeper data (location specified in zookeeper.conf), which cleared-off all the existing topologies.

Answer (score 1):

Run into same issue, also stuck there for couple days.
The way of cleaning zookeeper data worked for me.
But I found from another post use `--` to stop argument parsing.

```
 storm kill -- -local
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this but try the followings and see if it works -

1) Use pkill command to kill the topology

```
e.g: pkill local
```

2) run ps -ef | grep local
then find the process id for "-local" and then use this command -

```
 kill -9 {process-id of "-local" without using curly brackets}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I am not sure, but seems you're mixing it with Unix processes. Please note that this question is related to apache-storm framework, and "topology" is not an independent process. :)